# Need help solving a React Typescript error

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to convert a non-TS React component to using Typescript.
In this component I am getting this error:

> Class 'Component' defines instance member function
>   'componentWillMount', but extended class 'Root' defines it as instance
>   member property.

Here is my component:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";


import createStore from "./state";
import { getCurrentUser } from "./util";
import { setValidUser } from "./state/actions/auth-actions";
const { store } = createStore();

class Root extends React.Component<any> {

  componentWillMount = async () => {
    const currentUser = await getCurrentUser();

    if (currentUser) {
      store.dispatch(setValidUser(currentUser));
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
          <Router>
            {this.props.children}
          </Router>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default (Component, props = {}) => {
  render(
    <Root>
      <Component {...props} />
    </Root>,
    document.getElementById("root"),
  );
};
```

I am not a pro at TS yet, obvioulsy, and not sure how to resolve this. thanks!

Comment: What are you doing by this -> `import * as React from "react";`? it should be `import React from "react";`

Comment: using @types/react, you must use `import * as React from "react"`, otherwise you will get 'has no default export' errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Class 'Component' defines instance member function 'componentWillMount', but extended class 'Root' defines it as instance member property.

Change your property:

```
componentWillMount = async () => {
```

to a member function:

```
async componentWillMount() {
```

These names [come from OO concepts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_(computer_programming))

## More

I would even:

```
 componentWillMount() {
    this.asyncMount();
 }

 asyncMount = async () => {
    const currentUser = await getCurrentUser();

    if (currentUser) {
      store.dispatch(setValidUser(currentUser));
    }
  }
```

As React will not wait for your `componentWillMount` to wait and its async nature might confuse your fellow developers.

Comment: Can you take some time to explain the differences between these two syntaxes?

Comment: One is a class with a function and the other is a class with a variable that is a function.

Comment: Thanks so much for clarifying this!. Yep it fixed the errors.